# автообновление парсера php

Tags: php, парсер

Есть парсер на php,

```
 $url =('https://myfin.by/crypto-rates/bitcoin-rub');
    $file = file_get_contents($url);
    $file1 = str_get_html($file);

    $pars = $file1->find('.birzha_info_head_rates',1)->find('span',0);
    $result = substr($pars, 7, -8);

   echo  '<span>Изменения за 24ч</span><span id="fon2" class="p"> '.$pars.'</span>';
```

он берет значения изменения криптовалют с сайта.
Вопрос в том, как сделать его автообновление без перезагрузки страницы, чтобы обновлялся только тег с числом, который парсится
например сайт exmo.me, на главной странице у них курсы которые обновляются каждую секунду. Спасибо

Comment: Ajax вам в помощь

Comment: Средствами PHP это не реализуется. Вам нужно создать PHP-страницу, которая будет парсить нужное значение и выводить его, а затем использовать JQuery AJAX, чтобы подключить эту страницу и обновлять значения в тэге на стороне клиента